# pysctp installation error in windows 7 , 64-bit system

Tags: python, sctp

While installing pysctp in windows got the error in windows. How to solve this issue.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the libraries using the windows powershell.Seems to work for me all the time .
enter the following command:
py -m pip install libraryname